# Find all DATEDIFFs within a certain timeframe 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like [image]

with a composite key of `patientid, admissiondate, dischargedate`.

Notice that `patientID 6` has a `dischargedate` of 10/21 and an `admissiondate` of 10/22.

Also `patientID 11` has a `dischargedate` of 2/20 and an `admissiondate` of 6/14.

There is no limit to the number of times a `patientID` can be in the database.

How can I get a list of all the instances where an `admissiondate` was 3 or less days greater than the previous `dischargedate`? (`patientid 6` fits this bill).  It can't be right self join multiple times. I have

```
select  patientid, p.admissiondate, p.dischargedate
    from Patient as p
    where patientid in
    (
        select patientid
            from Patient p2
            group by patientid
            having count(*) > 1
    )
    order by patientid, admissiondate
```

To get a list of all people seen more than once. How can I make sure that `admissionDate` is within three days after `dischargedate`? (from the previous row in this example).

I can't do a simple `datediff(dd,admissiondate, dischargedate)` because I'm not worried about the `datediff` on any one visit, just that the NEXT `admissiondate` came within three days of the previous `dischargedate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;with cte as
(
     -- get admission dates by patient in order
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PatientID order by AdmissionDate) as AdOrd 
from patient
)
     -- find the gaps between adjacent admissions
    select admissions.patientid, discharges.dischargedate, admissions.admissiondate     
    from cte admissions
        inner join cte discharges on discharges.patientid=admissions.patientid
            and discharges.AdOrd = admissions.AdOrd-1
    where DATEDIFF(D,discharges.dischargedate,admissions.admissiondate )<=3
```

Comment: this looks like it works.  could you explain `and c2.AdOrd = c1.AdOrd-1`.  what does the -1 provide?

Comment: Since `AdOrd` is based on the order of your `AdmissionDate`, this condition satisfies your requirement that you only want to compare to `... the previous dischargedate`

Comment: i'm not quite understanding joining on the previous row number with equal admissiondates.

Comment: AdOrd represents the admission order for the particular patient : 1 is the first admission, 2 the second, etc. Given that, we find the previous discharge by taking the current admission order - 1. Let me rename the tables to clarify